# How to use paging with Repeater control in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, pagination, repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepCourse" runat="server">

  <ItemTemplate>

    <div style="width:400px"></div>

    <div class="course" style="float: left; margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 100px">

      <div class="image">
        <asp:Image ID="imgteacher" runat="server" Height="150" Width="248" ImageUrl='<%# "ShowImage.ashx?id="+ DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseID") %>'/>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-left: 3px; width: 250px">
        <div class="name">
          <a href="#"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblname" Text='<%#Eval("CourseName") %>'></asp:Label></a>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 13px"></div>
        <div id="teacher">
          <a href="#"><%#Eval("UserName") %> </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div style="height: 4px"></div>

      <div class="date">
        <div id="datebegin">
          <asp:Label ID="lbldatebegin" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BeginDate") %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div id="dateend">
          <asp:Label ID="lbldateend" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ClosingDate") %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

In my project `Repeater Control` works fine. And now I need pagination for replacing those data. But I don't have any information about this. May be someone give me advice about this issue.

As shown below picture.

[image]

Comment: maybe this would help you: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Paging-in-Repeater-control-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's no built-in pagination in the Repeater control, but based on [this](http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2013/05/custom-paging-in-repeater-control-in.html#.U0JMPfmSwYo) article, you can achieve pagination in the Repeater control by creating another Repeater control for pages and use `PagedDataSource` as it's source.

First, add this to your markup:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">

<asp:Repeater ID="rptPaging" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptPaging_ItemCommand">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnPage"
   style="padding:8px;margin:2px;background:#ffa100;border:solid 1px #666;font:8pt tahoma;"
   CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>"
   runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True">
    <%# Container.DataItem %>
  </asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

</div>
```

Next, add the following property in your code behind:

```
//This property will contain the current page number 
public int PageNumber
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["PageNumber"] != null)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["PageNumber"]);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    set { ViewState["PageNumber"] = value; }
}
```

Finally add the following methods:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindRepeater();
}

private void BindRepeater()
{
    //Do your database connection stuff and get your data
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from YourTable";

    //save the result in data table
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
    ad.Fill(dt);

    //Create the PagedDataSource that will be used in paging
    PagedDataSource pgitems = new PagedDataSource();
    pgitems.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    pgitems.AllowPaging = true;

    //Control page size from here 
    pgitems.PageSize = 4;
    pgitems.CurrentPageIndex = PageNumber;
    if (pgitems.PageCount > 1)
    {
        rptPaging.Visible = true;
        ArrayList pages = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i <= pgitems.PageCount - 1; i++)
        {
            pages.Add((i + 1).ToString());
        }
        rptPaging.DataSource = pages;
        rptPaging.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        rptPaging.Visible = false;
    }

    //Finally, set the datasource of the repeater
    RepCourse.DataSource = pgitems;
    RepCourse.DataBind();
}

//This method will fire when clicking on the page no link from the pager repeater
protected void rptPaging_ItemCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    PageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) - 1;
    BindRepeater();
}
```

Please give it a try and if you faced any issue just inform me.

**Edit: Alternative Solution**

Another excellent solution can be found [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rizwan328/datalist-custom-paging-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp/), this solution includes **the Navigation buttons of pages**. You'll need to download files from that link to see a functional pagination and just replace the DataList control with your Repeater control.

Hope this helps.