# How to implement a grid like structure instead of tabular structure using jquery DataTables in ASP.NET using Ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, datatables

I have to use datatable and make things like given in the image

[I want my ui to look like this using data tables instead that they are normally shown in table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFPdY.jpg)

the data must be picked from the database and then retrieved by ajax  the retrieve function will be looking like

```
public static List<string[]> AllItems()
{
    List<string[]> ItemList = new List<string[]>();
    using (MySqlConnection exmp = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand getAllItems = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            getAllItems.Connection = exmp;
            getAllItems.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            getAllItems.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table1";

            exmp.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = getAllItems.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string[] temp = new string[8];
                //Item Name
                temp[0] = reader[0].ToString();
                // Item Nick Name
                temp[1] = reader[1].ToString();
                //Item property
                temp[2] = reader[2].ToString();
                //Item Image URl
                temp[3] = reader[3].toString();
                //Item Price
                temp[4] = reader[4].toString();
                //Item Special Property that makes a link
                temp[5] = reader[5].toString();

                ItemList.Add(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    return ItemList;
}
```

My ajax function to retrieve json

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "default.aspx/AllItems",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess
        });
```

Now using the code given above for retrieving data from database, I have to make a structure as given in the pic mentioned above using datatables How can I do it?

Please provide some sample code; I'll be grateful to you.

Comment: webforms ? MVC ? Webforms has repeater control that you can use. In MVC you can create a div that looks like first section and then iterate over your result to append results.

Comment: webforms, but i preffer datatables because i need to include search and pagination feature to which datatables provides easily

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904666/using-pagination-with-repeater-control-in-asp-net-web-form check this answer

Comment: still i think datatables will be good because i have to make search function which will be  tough and require more effort