# ASP.NET Repeater add pager

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to add paging for content foremed using repeaters

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
         <!--One card-->
            <div class="card" style="width: 90%">
               <div class="card-body"> 
                  <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>      
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </ItemTemplate>            
</asp:Repeater>
```

By doing this i get cards according to the data in the database one under the other
this will not be practical if there are a lot of data

will i be able to implement paging for this

```
First 1 2 3...... Last
```

I am not using a datatable `DataTable dt = new DataTable();`

I am using `DataSet ds = new DataSet();`

How to change the code

```
//save the result in data table     
DataTable dt = new DataTable();     
ad.SelectCommand = cmd;     
ad.Fill(dt);      
//Create the PagedDataSource that will be used in paging     
PagedDataSource pgitems = new PagedDataSource();     
pgitems.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;     
pgitems.AllowPaging = true;
```

according to the one i use below

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();           
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);             
da.Fill(ds);                          
Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
```

I cant put

```
pgitems.DataSource = ds.DefaultView;
```

it gives me an error

Comment: How is this related to the SQL _language_?

Comment: Here is some example it may help but you will require to learn many things https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/paging-using-repeater-control-in-asp-net-with-and-without-stored-procedure/

Comment: I've removed the SQL tag for you. If you need help with your query, please re-add the SQL tag, and add the query to your question.

Comment: Similar to this? [How to use paging with Repeater control in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904666/how-to-use-paging-with-repeater-control-in-asp-net)

Comment: @Pirate in the link you provided it has
`//save the result in data table
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
    ad.Fill(dt);

    //Create the PagedDataSource that will be used in paging
    PagedDataSource pgitems = new PagedDataSource();
    pgitems.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    pgitems.AllowPaging = true;`

but i use `DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            
            Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
            Repeater1.DataBind();`

error  at `dt.DefaultView;`

Comment: You know a DataSet uses a DataTable, right?

Comment: I dont know how to convert it would be a great help if u can write that coding lines because when i put ds.DefaultView it gives an error